# Can we say that an angle is acute?

Tags: geometry

Consider a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with sides $BC=a, AC=b$ and $AB=c$. If we show that $b\le c$, then $b$ is not the longest side of the triangle. Does this mean $\angle ABC$ is acute and why? I extracted this from a problem that I am solving and I want to clear it out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In axiomatic approach, you can use two facts:

1. An angle opposite to longer side is greater than an angle opposite to shorter side.
2. In any triangle at least two angles are acute.

For the proofs see *Foundations of geometry* by K.Borsuk and W.Szmielew (page 100 and page 117)

Sidenote: Both these theorems as well as original problem hold in neutral geometry i.e. without parallel postulate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,by law of cosines,we have $$cos\angle ABC=\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ab}>0$$So $\angle ABC$is acute.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with the fact that in the triangle the longest side oppose the largest angle, you can show that if $b<c$, then $\beta < \gamma$. However, if $\beta>90^\circ$, then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma>\beta+\gamma>2\beta>180^\circ$ which cannot happen.